# corefonts or fonts-liberation in wine

Tags: docker, debian, wine

I am running a *debian 9* *docker* container with a *wine* program installed in it.

I want to have MS *corefonts* support. e.g. Arial, Courier, Comic Sans etc. My current approach is to call

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/20171222/src/winetricks -O /usr/local/bin/winetricks
chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/winetricks
winetricks corefonts
```

which also requires `wget`, `ca-certificates` and `cabextract` to be present.

On the [debian package page](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/ttf-mscorefonts-installer) there is a recommendation to use [fonts-liberation](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/fonts-liberation).

Is it a better approach to install [msttcorefonts](https://packages.debian.org/source/stretch/msttcorefonts) or [fonts-liberation](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/fonts-liberation) via *apt* instead of *winetricks* and what are the downsides of using `apt install fonts-liberation` in exchange for `winetricks corefonts`?

Answer (score 0):

this is what I do on ubuntu 18, hope it helps:

```sh
# auto accept the msft EULA
echo ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true | debconf-set-selections
apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```